# Printing dimensional array to table

Tags: php, html

I have a question about array. I've got this type array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Project
            [1] => Time
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Google
            [1] => 29,92
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mozzila
            [1] => 5,96
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Firefox
            [1] => 215,3
        )
```

How could I print it into my table:

```
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 50%;">'.$project.'</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 50%;">'.$time.'</td>
```

I would be very thankful if you could help me, to solve this script. Because I am stuck. It would look like:

Project  |  Time
Google   |  29,92
Mozzila  |  5,96

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
<table>
<?php 
foreach($data as $key => $line) {
    $project = $line[0];
    $time = $line[1];
?>
<tr>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 50%;"><?=$project;?></td>
    <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 50%;"><?=$time;?></td>
</td>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a foreach:

```
echo '<table>';
foreach($data AS $row){
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach($row AS $cell){
      echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

PS: It's Mozilla not Mozzila ;)

Comment: Well yes, but only for the array definition part. It sounds like he already has the array defined, that was for an example.

Comment: I actually updated it to remove that part, since he included his array variable in the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
foreach( $data as $k => $item ){
?>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 50%;"><?php echo $item[0]; ?></td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 50%;"><?php echo $item[1]; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

There are some other improvements, which you could also make, which would make the code cleaner, such as moving the CSS styling to either a stylesheet, or to a set of style tags in the head of your document:

```
td.tableData { border: 1px solid #000; width: 50%; }
```

And then the code changes to:

```
<?php
foreach( $data as $k => $item ){
?>
        <td class="tableData"><?php echo $item[0]; ?></td>
        <td class="tableData"><?php echo $item[1]; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Or even better:

```
#TheIDofTheTableToStyle td { border: 1px solid #000; width: 50%; }
```

And then:

```
<table id="TheIDofTheTableToStyle">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
foreach( $data as $k => $item ){
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $item[0]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $item[1]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```